# Python/Kivy : How to put dynamic label widget and value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have two file `test.py` and `test.kv` .
i run `test.py` then shows `show` button.
When i click on `show` button then `def abc` call.Can someone tell me how to show array in dynamic label and value(Item1=5000.Item2=1000).
Item1   5000
Item2   1000

I am using array
    arr = ({'Item1': 5000},{'Item2': 1000})

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (600, 600)

class Invoice(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Invoice, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def abc(self):
        #fetching from database
        arr = ({'Item1': 5000},{'Item2': 1000})
        print(arr)

class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<Button@Button>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'
    size_hint_y:None
    height: 30

<Label@Label>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'
    size_hint_y:None
    height: 30

Invoice:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 15, 15

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding : 5, 5
            size_hint: .6, None
            pos_hint: {'x': .18,}


            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                padding : 5, 5
                spacing: 10, 10
                size: 800, 40
                size_hint: 1, None

                Button:
                    text: "Show"
                    size_hint_x: .05
                    spacing_x: 30
                    on_press:root.abc()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1, 1

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint: .5, 1
                padding : 0, 15
                spacing: 10, 10
                size: 500, 30

                Button:
                    text: "Invoice"
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'middle'

                GridLayout:
                    cols: 2
                    #orientation: "horizontal"
                    padding : 5, 0
                    spacing: 10, 0
                    #size: 500, 30
                    size_hint: 1, 1
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: .35
                        text: "Item1"
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign: 'left'
                        valign: 'middle'
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgb: .6, .6, .6
                            Rectangle:
                                pos: self.pos
                                size: self.size

                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: .15
                        text: "5000"
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign: 'right'
                        valign: 'middle'
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgb: .6, .6, .6
                            Rectangle:
                                pos: self.pos
                                size: self.size
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the option to iterate over the data and generate the widget dynamically is an option, the truth is that it is unbeatable in the long term. If you have structured information it is appropriate to use a design pattern and kivy offers to use a [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) for these cases, this implements the `MVC` pattern, so we just need to pass the data and establish a view where an appropriate adapter can be provided.

In your case it is enough to design a widget that is what is shown in each row:

```
<Item@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    text: "" # new property
    value: 0 # new property
    padding : 5, 0
    spacing: 10, 0
    Label:
        size_hint_x: .35
        text: root.text
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: .6, .6, .6
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

    Label:
        size_hint_x: .15
        text: str(root.value)
        halign: 'right'
        valign: 'middle'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: .6, .6, .6
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

And then replace the `GridLayout` with the `RecycleView`:

```
RecycleView:
    id: rv
    viewclass: 'Item'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(30)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

And in the event of the button assign the data, in this case you must convert your data to a list of dictionaries where the fields will be the text and value attribute of Item:

```
def convert_data(data):
    l = []
    for item in data:
        for key, value in item.items():
            l.append({'text': key, 'value': value})
    return l

class Invoice(Screen):
    def abc(self):
        #fetching from database
        arr = ({'Item1': 5000},{'Item2': 1000})

        # convert to [{'text': 'Item1', 'value': 5000}, {'text': 'Item2', 'value': 1000}]
        self.rv.data = convert_data(arr)
```

Complete Code:

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

def convert_data(data):
    l = []
    for item in data:
        for key, value in item.items():
            l.append({'text': key, 'value': value})
    return l

class Invoice(Screen):
    def abc(self):
        #fetching from database
        arr = ({'Item1': 5000},{'Item2': 1000})

        # convert to [{'text': 'Item1', 'value': 5000}, {'text': 'Item2', 'value': 1000}]
        self.rv.data = convert_data(arr)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('test.kv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**test.kv**

```
<Button@Button>:
    font_size: 15
    size_hint_y:None
    height: 30

<Label@Label>:
    font_size: 15
    size_hint_y:None
    height: 30

<Item@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    text: ""
    value: 0
    padding : 5, 0
    spacing: 10, 0
    Label:
        size_hint_x: .35
        text: root.text
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: .6, .6, .6
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

    Label:
        size_hint_x: .15
        text: str(root.value)
        halign: 'right'
        valign: 'middle'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: .6, .6, .6
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

Invoice:
    rv: rv
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 15, 15

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding : 5, 5
            size_hint: .6, None
            pos_hint: {'x': .18,}


            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                padding : 5, 5
                spacing: 10, 10
                size: 800, 40
                size_hint: 1, None

                Button:
                    text: "Show"
                    size_hint_x: .05
                    spacing_x: 30
                    on_press:root.abc()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1, 1

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint: .5, 1
                padding : 0, 15
                spacing: 10, 10
                size: 500, 30

                Button:
                    text: "Invoice"
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'middle'

                BoxLayout:
                    RecycleView:
                        id: rv
                        viewclass: 'Item'
                        RecycleBoxLayout:
                            default_size: None, dp(30)
                            default_size_hint: 1, None
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.minimum_height
                            orientation: 'vertical'
```

Answer (score 5):

In your `abc()` method you can create labels and add them to your layout. In order to do that, I made a few change to your code. I added an `id` to your `GridLayout` and changed your custom label class to `MyLabel` and added it to the `py` file, so that I could create them in Python. Here is the modified Python file:

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (600, 600)

class MyLabel(Label):
    pass

class Invoice(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Invoice, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def abc(self):
        #fetching from database
        arr = ({'Item1': 5000},{'Item2': 1000})
        layout = self.ids['invoices']
        for invoice in arr:
            for key,val in invoice.items():
                lab1 = MyLabel(text=str(key),size_hint_x=.35, halign='left' )
                lab2 = MyLabel(text=str(val),size_hint_x=.15, halign='right' )
                layout.add_widget(lab1)
                layout.add_widget(lab2)

class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root
```

And changes to the `kv` file included changing `Label` to `MyLabel`, moving as much as possible to the `MyLabel` class, and removing your example labels:

```
<Button@Button>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'
    size_hint_y:None
    height: 30

<MyLabel>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'
    size_hint_y:None
    height: 30
    text_size: self.size
    valign: 'middle'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .6, .6, .6
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

Invoice:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 15, 15

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding : 5, 5
            size_hint: .6, None
            pos_hint: {'x': .18,}


            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                padding : 5, 5
                spacing: 10, 10
                size: 800, 40
                size_hint: 1, None

                Button:
                    text: "Show"
                    size_hint_x: .05
                    spacing_x: 30
                    on_press:root.abc()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1, 1

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint: .5, 1
                padding : 0, 15
                spacing: 10, 10
                size: 500, 30

                Button:
                    text: "Invoice"
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'middle'

                GridLayout:
                    id: invoices
                    cols: 2
                    #orientation: "horizontal"
                    padding : 5, 0
                    spacing: 10, 0
                    #size: 500, 30
                    size_hint: 1, 1
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
```